# In Laravel 4.1, is there a way of having a route to run `Artisan::call('up')`?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, laravel-artisan

Currently I have a working route for **putting my application into** maintenance mode using the standard Laravel way.

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == Role::ADMIN){
        //A route to shut down the application, user must be an authenticated Admin user
        Route::get('shut/the/application/down', function(){
            Artisan::call('down');
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately I cannot get a similar route to work for **bringing my application out of** maintenance mode using `Artisan::call('up')`.

How could I do this **using Artisan** and a route instead of having to create custom logic? I realise my app is inaccessible whilst in maintenance mode but putting `Artisan::call('up')` in my routes file works, however wrapping it as a route does not. I want to know if there is any way around this.

Comment: Not sure why this is marked as a duplicate - the duplicate thread states 'without using Artisan' whereas I want to use Artisan...

Comment: Read the thread, they use Artisan, in fact, the code you've used is in there. The title is just misleading as OP of that question didn't understand how to accomplish this using Artisan, so they thought something else was required, it wasn't.

Comment: Regarding the top answer, the only mention of Artisan is without a route - my question is about using Artisan with a route. Where routes are mentioned it is custom code that's being used as they are creating 'my.down' rather than relying on the usual 'down' file as used by Artisan. My code snippet is not mentioned in the thread although similar to the others.